# Android App widget pendingIntent

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am sending an action with a pendingIntent but onRecieve() cant see this action ? how can I handle it ?

and I am not taking any error. and  when I look the logs. I have seen only UPDATE ,ENABLED,DISABLE,DELETED actions

public class WidgetDeneme extends AppWidgetProvider {

```
final String TAG = WidgetDeneme.class.getSimpleName();
final String APPWIDGET_BUTTON_CLICK = "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_BUTTON_CLICK";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Log.e(TAG,TAG);
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,WidgetDeneme.class);
        intent.setAction(APPWIDGET_BUTTON_CLICK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
        // to the button
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pendingIntent);

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e(TAG,intent.getAction());
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

}

---

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".WidgetDeneme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_BUTTON_CLICK" />

        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you please post your LogCat error and your onRecive() code?

Comment: post full code.. onRecive(), Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create `RemoteViews` using the correct layout

```
    // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,WidgetDeneme.class);
    intent.setAction(APPWIDGET_BUTTON_CLICK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
    // to the button
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pendingIntent);

    // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

Note `R.layout.widget` instead of `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`. Make sure you actually use the name you gave to the layout, you will find it in the res/layout folder. See [Android developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) for more information.